# how to get datetime from json in swift 3

Tags: json, swift3, datetime-format

I have a problem about get datetime formate from json(PHP) with Alamofire

PHP json return

> "mydata="[{  "id" : "001",  "now_in": {
>                   "date": "2017-11-28 17:44:44.000000",
>                   "timezone_type": 3,
>                   "timezone": "Asia/Krasnoyarsk"
>               },  }]

My code

```
    var dataArray =  [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
//---------------------- get value from json -------------------------------
      Alamofire.request("http://111.72.4.81/SQL/Service.php").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["mydata"].arrayObject {
                    self.dataArray = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }

            }
        }
  //------------------- print array ----------------------------
  var dict = dataArray[indexPath.row]
  let keys = dict["now_in"]
  print(keys)
```

I need format

> now_in = "2017-11-28 17:44:44.000000"

but output is

> Optional({
>       date = "2017-11-28 17:44:44.000000";
>       timezone = "Asia/Krasnoyarsk";
>       "timezone_type" = 3; })

Comment: Are you having trouble in getting the correct value from Dictionary or parsing it in a Date object?

Comment: yes, i need to get datetime from dictionary

Comment: Can you post the JSON you receive from your PHP service? Maybe as an edit to your question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: print your `swiftyJsonVar` and post output here

Comment: This is siftyJsonVar
//----------------------//
mydata =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            "now_in" =             {
                date = "2017-11-28 17:44:44.000000";
                timezone = "Asia/Krasnoyarsk";
                "timezone_type" = 3;
            };
         },

         {
            id = 2;
            "now_in" =             {
                date = "2017-11-29 17:45:44.000000";
                timezone = "Asia/Krasnoyarsk";
                "timezone_type" = 3;
            };
         },
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let dateString = dict["now_in"]!["date"]`

will give you the date string. If you want Date object you can parse it using

```
let format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Comment: it's work for "dict["now_in"]!["date"] as! String" but convert to date is nil

Comment: Fixed and tested the answer.

Comment: I change to  format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" but it have optional

Comment: Perform a conditional unwrapping. I will edit the answer when i get to my laptop

Comment: This date format will return `nil`. It's not an ISO8601 date and the fractional seconds are not considered.

Answer (score 0):

The value for key `now_in` is another dictionary. The key of the value you are looking for is `date`

```
let dict = dataArray[indexPath.row]
if let dateInfo = dict["now_in"] as? [String:Any],
   let date = dateInfo["date"] as? String {
   print(date)
}
```

You can use a `DateFormatter` to create a `Date`. The date format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`.

Comment: if let dateInfo = dict["now_in"] as? [String:Any],
            let date = dateInfo["date"] as? String {
            let format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = format
            let dates = formatter.date(from: dateString)
            print(dates)
        }
the output is  Optional(2018-01-30 23:30:28 +0000)

Comment: Of course it's optional because `date(from:` returns an optional. If the date is always in this format you can force unwrap the date `formatter.date(from: dateString)!`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @vadian and Huanid

for as you advise me, right now  it's work

```
 let dateString = (dict["now_in"]! as! [String: AnyObject])["date"]! as! String
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_en")
            let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            print("\(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
```

Comment: I want to make clear that I didn't advise `[String: AnyObject]` (it has to be `[String:Any]`) and I didn't advise to force unwrap the dictionary values.

Comment: [String:Any] it work also, but when i convert to date is cannot unwrap